VB,net to MariaDB Server: Incorrect String Value
I have tried configuring MariabDB Server Character set and Collation to UTF8MB4 & UTF8MB4_UNICODE_CI OR UTF8MB4_GENERAL_CI

[MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver][mysqld-11.4.2-MariaDB]Incorrect string value: '\xB2' for column itis.mrfmon_tbl.short_description at row 1

here is my connection string:
Dim s As String = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver};Server=" & _server & ";Database=itis;User=itams;Password=P@ssw0rd.;CHARSET=UTF8MB4"


Does CharSet=utf8; work? From connectionstrings.com: "Note! Use lower case value utf8 and not upper case UTF8 as this will fail."

\B2 sounds like "latin1", not ahy variant of utf8.

MariaDB has a MariaDB ODBC conenctor that works and is tested against MariaDB server.
